# Can I say if(4 < $a < 44) instead of if(4 < $a && $a < 44)? (php)

Tags: php, operators

Can I use `if(4 <= $a <= 44)` instead of `if(4 <= $a && $a <= 44)`?

Comment: PHP wasn't made to be a cool and easy language. Python was.

Comment: Will raise a **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL**

Comment: Sometimes I'm shocked how lazy people can be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

`if(4 <= $a <= 44)` is equivalent to `if((4 <= $a) <= 44)`. This may be equivalent to `if(false <= 44)` or `if(true <= 44)`, neither of which makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

<strike>`if(4 <= $a <= 44)` will (I believe) be parsed as `if ((4 <= $a) <= 44)`, which checks whether `(4 <= $a)` (which is either 0 or 1) is less than 44.</strike>

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't (as all others already said).

*Comparison operators* in PHP, as their name implies, allow you to compare two values, and with the expression

```
4 <= $a <= 44
```

you would be comparing three values. Read [here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for a complete explanation.